# Spring boot security doesn't redirect oauth/authorize calls on configure(HttpSecurity http) method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, oauth

I'm setting up a new server, so I'm on the point when I have to configure the server to allow some URLs to access without authenticating and I'm getting some problems. 
All is working fine excepting /oauth/authorize, because on the last action, when entering the credentials, page is not redirecting and stays on the same one.

The code I tried is the following, that allows me to access to the URLs without any kind of authentication, but the /oauth/authorize redirect doesn't work

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/oauth/token", "/oauth/authorize**", "/login**", "/user/recover_password", "/user/register").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .and()
        .logout().logoutUrl("/oauth/logout")
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

So, as I said, I need to access to this URLs without authenticating and also be able to redirect on the /oauth/authorize to be able to logged in with some external resources. But what I'm getting is that when I enter my credentials, the page stays on the same one.

Comment: can you try adding a filter like 
addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

Comment: can you provide me any more info, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so, finally I found the fix and it's working now, adding a sessionManagement, although I don't know exactly why.

I added the following code:

```
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
        .and()
```

So, the full method should see like that:

```
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http.
      .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/oauth/token", "/oauth/authorize**", "/login**", "/user/recover_password", "/user/register").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .and()
        .logout().logoutUrl("/oauth/logout")
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Now, the /oauth/authorize is working as expected and my public URLs are also accessible without authenticate.

So, for now, if anyone can explain what sessionManagement does, it will be nice.